# Delete 1000k records from table asynchronously using sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I want to delete more than 1000k records (some times millions of records) from a table. I feel it is safe to do asynchronously using sidekiq and Redis, as I am using Ruby and Sinatra.

**When exactly I should call the sidekiq's "perform" method? Where exactly I need to run the loop of the records I need to delete? 
Can anyone explain how the records to be deleted are put in queue using sidekiq?**

Here is my code, please check and let me know whether I am following right code.

In my User controller:

```
def delete_user
   DeleteUserWorker.perform_async(@client_info, @input_params)
end
```

In my lib/workers/deleteuser_worker.rb

```
class DeleteUserWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(client_info, input_params)
       # executes the query and fetches non-active records from users table.
      @delete_users = User.where("status != ? and EndDate < ?", "active", 3.months.ago )
      @delete_users.each do |user|
         user.destroy!
      end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to iterate over millions of records you should use find_each or find_in_batches instead of each (since .each will try to instantiate all the objects at once):

```
  @delete_users.find_each do |user|
     user.destroy!
  end
```

More info: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html